# React parent property function not firing when called from child function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my parent component i have a function called `handleDocumentSubmission` which i want to pass down to the child.

```
  handleDocumentSubmission = input => async (e) => {
       console.log("fired");
```

I then render the following component like this. I use the same function name.

```
  <FrontConfirm
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    handleReview={this.handleReview}
                    values={values}
                    handleDocumentSubmission={this.handleDocumentSubmission}
                />
```

Now in my child component i want to call this function from a child function on click of a button.

```
  continue = () => {
        console.log("clicked", this.props);
        this.props.handleDocumentSubmission("front");
    };

<Button onClick={this.continue}
  variant="contained" color="primary">
  Confirm
</Button>
```

Now the console log for clicked i can see with props that has my handleDocumentSubmission function. But the console.log from the parent function `console.log("fired")` Does not get called.

Comment: As you're using an async function, you should `await this.props.handleDocumentSubmission("front");` in the `continue` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `handleDocumentSubmission` is a curried function that accepts 2 sets of parameters. By using the following syntax and passing your event param, it will work :

```
continue = ev => {
    console.log("clicked", this.props);
    this.props.handleDocumentSubmission("front")(ev);
};
```

Your function will also not need to be asynchrinous :

```
handleDocumentSubmission = input => e => {
    console.log("fired");
}
```

The final syntax without the `continue` function (I assume you created it for testing) will be the following :

```
<Button onClick={this.props.handleDocumentSubmission("front")}
    variant="contained" color="primary">
    Confirm
</Button>
```

Using this, your function will receive both your value (`front`) and the event information when fired.

---

Having a synchronous function will not prevent it from returning a value :

```
handleDocumentSubmission = input => e => {
    console.log("fired");
    return 'success'
}

continue = ev => {
    console.log("clicked", this.props);
    const result = this.props.handleDocumentSubmission("front")(ev);
    console.log(result)
};
```

If you really want it to be `async`, use the `await` keyword :

```
handleDocumentSubmission = input => async e => {
    console.log("fired");
    return /* A promise  */
}

continue = async ev => {
    console.log("clicked", this.props);
    const result = await this.props.handleDocumentSubmission("front")(ev);
    console.log(result)
};
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention handleDocumentSubmission needs to be asynchornous i want to return success or fail information to the child in the conintue function based on something that happens in "handleDocumentSubmission".

Comment: So continue will be async aswell becasue its waiting for the response from handleDocumentSubmission. handleDocumentSubmission will do an async call and return a success or failure response which should be read by continue.